# NSDateFormatter in iPad issue

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have this `NSString` :

```
2010-05-29T16:31:49.000Z
```

And i want to convert it to NSDate with this method:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *date = nil;
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateSting];
```

And when i run it date is equal to Nil, Any idea why it happens?

It's happen only in iPad, and in iPhone it work perfectly.....

Comment: Just a stab in the dark: Do your iPad's time/date settings vary from the iPhone in *any way*?

Comment: Please check, I have edited my answer to meeting the ISO8601 way of parsing the date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note from http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime. Thanks to [borrrden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155387/borrrden) for bringing this to notice.

> Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a
>   special UTC designator ("Z").

```
NSString *inputString = @"2010-05-29T16:31:49.000Z";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:inputString];
```

Comment: T is, but Z actually means "UTC" (as opposed to writing -01:00, etc).  So be careful about this.  This string is ISO8601, and should be parsed as such.  See http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: @borrrden Thanks for bringing this to notice. I have referred the dateFormats specified in [NSDateFormatter](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-19.html#Date_Format_Patterns), couldn't find a counterpart so used a fallback. Please see if this is enough

Comment: Small letter z is enough, as I found out recently.  In iOS 6+ there is a new specifier for ISO8601 (ZZZZZ), but that doesn't help for iOS 5.  NSDateFormatters seems to understand the Z designator in date strings.  Also, if all OP gets is "Z" then it doesn't matter if he parses it or ignores it really.  However, I am concerned about future people reading this post.

Comment: @Anupdas, Hi but this solution is not working in case of "2013-06-04T16:55:00Z" This string. Can you please help me. Thanks +1

Comment: @Mangesh Can you verify if its `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz` or `yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ssz`?

Comment: @Anupdas, it is "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz". Thanks for quick responce

Comment: @Mangesh I just worked it out, it is working fine. If you can send  relevant code to my mail I can check what is going wrong.

Comment: Thanks for quick responce, Code is : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17120767/need-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsdate/17120823#17120823

Comment: @Mangesh I'm sorry to say this but, I don't find any others issues except the dataFormat. This is how I verified it `NSString * dateString = @"2013-06-04T16:55:00Z";
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];
    NSDate * date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];`

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked many times already. Your formatter is invalid for your input string:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX
```

Not sure which one of the time-zone patterns you are using, so maybe `XXX` or `XXXX` should be used at the end.

See http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html. Note that `Z` is not allowed for time-zone pattern `ZZZ`.

Comment: Note that the formatter behavior changed between iOS 5 and iOS 6. You should always have a correct format pattern because you can't be sure if a slightly incorrect pattern will work or not.